# Colocar ícone no atalho de um site no Android

Tags: html

Olá, estou com a seguinte dúvida, tenho meu site, totalmente responsivo, e para alguns de nossos clientes, nós colocamos um atalho do site no celular, pelo Google Chrome. O atalho funciona mas fica um ícone totalmente aleatório em relação ao meu site.

Quero que funcione como o Tecmundo, Globo.com, todos estes sites, quando vamos adicionar um atalho deles no celular já trás o ícone do site.

Fiz isso mas não deu certo.

```
   <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="images/favicon.ico"/>
```

Funciona no computador normalmente aparecendo o ícone lá em cima ao lado do título.

SOLUÇÂO

```
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
        <!-- Opera Speed Dial Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icon/favicon.png" />
    <!-- Standard Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/icon/favicon.ico" />
    <!-- For iPhone 4 Retina display: -->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="images/icon/apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png">
    <!-- For iPad: -->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="images/icon/apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png">
    <!-- For iPhone: -->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="images/icon/apple-touch-icon-57x57-precomposed.png">
```

Comment: Esse serviço já cria os ícones para diversos dispositivos com opção para personalizar cores etc ... http://realfavicongenerator.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caso a imagem que irá inserir seja do tipo `.ico`, você deve definir o *type* o `image/x-icon`. Veja abaixo:

```
<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Para outros formatos de imagens como `.png` e `.gif`, veja abaixo como deve ser:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="images/favicon.gif" />
```

Para deixar registrado, deixei um arquivo [**favicons.html** no Github](https://github.com/cleidimarviana/SOpt/blob/master/HTML/favicons.html). Veja também mais detalhes [nestes exemplos de favicons](http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/examples/favicons/)<sup>(en)</sup>.

Comment: Aproveitei o link que você deixou e já fiz para todos dispositivos.
Deu Certo

Comment: @LucasMarques legal cara... boa sorte ai! =)

Answer (score -1):

Amigo, você quer colocar um `favicon` nos site.

Faça o seguinte:

1 - Edite uma imagem que você deseja que apareça, no tamanho de 15X15 e salve a mesma com o nome `favicon.ico`

2 - Envie a imagem para onde estar hospedado a sua pagina `index.html`

3 - No código fonte da pagina `index.html` e nas pagina do site coloque este link abaixo:

```
<link href="/SEU SITE/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Exemplo:

O meu estou usando hospedagem gratuita da 000webhostapp ficou assim:

```
<link href="/https://lojasceess.000webhostapp.com/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Teste no meu site e veja se é assim (uma coroa aparece antes do nome da pagina)

https://lojasceess.000webhostapp.com/